# How to upgrade Magic Box?

Tags: apt, rpm, upgrade

I'm running Magic Box on Virtualbox.

Magic Box is a portuguese Linux System, based off of SuSE. At least, that's what it said on the Linux Family Tree. The version I have is V.12. There's the most up-to-date versions, like version 20.

How do I upgrade my system, though?

The system has apt-get, but some commands or options aren't there. It uses KDE 3.5. It was updated as well. It has Synaptic Package Manager too.

Comment: Can you provide links of this distro?

Comment: Sure will! 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caixa_M%C3%A1gica

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cm15kde.PNG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to check out my old Portuguese dictionary looking for this:

*Caixa Mágica* (Magic Box) has changed the distro is based of from RedHat to Debian, then Ubuntu since V.16. The official page offers no help about how to upgrade from one version to other.

My recommendation in this case is doing a fresh install (after backup) of the latest version downloading the ISO file from the [main download page](http://linux.caixamagica.pt/pag/b_down00.php). It would prevent headache, as things can go wire upgrading too many versions and it becomes worse if the base changes from version to another.

Comment: Huh, your right. I'll see what i can do with my VM.

Comment: Well, great. The VM's kernel doesn't have PAE.

Comment: @ThebotData why you need PAE? is a feature only useful for 32-bit kernels using more than 4GiB of memory RAM (among other things). Your VM don't really need PAE. If you use more than 4GiB of memory, just use the 64-bit version.

Comment: Well, upon inserting CM20, it says that the kernel needs PAE.

Comment: You are using 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: 32 bits. I used CM12 32 bit.

Comment: Try the 64-bit instead, also make sure your host system is 64-bit too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9754/discussion-between-the-bot-data-and-braiam)